# Get days interval from query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query which returns rows from specific days using the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` option.

My where clause was originally like this:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX  
BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AND
FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Which works, and hows me that the data that'll be processed is 139.5MB:

[image]

The thing is I want the "2" parameter to be dynamically loaded from a table, like this:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX  
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 
  (select value from `path.to.days_interval_setting`) DAY)) AND
          FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Now while the value is the same (2) The estimation now says it'll process 12.3 GB:
[image]

And it does in fact seem to be doing do, the query takes more time to run but the data returned is from the correct number of days.

I also tried joining the table instead of using a subquery and it gives the same results.

Anyone knows how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)

> Filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX that include subqueries cannot be used to limit the number of tables scanned for a wildcard table. For example, the following query does not limit the tables scanned for the wildcard table bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod19*
>
> To limit it based on the condition involving the subquery, you can
>   perform two separate queries.
>
> First query:

```
#standardSQL
# Get the list of tables that match the required table name prefixes
SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(table_id), LENGTH('gsod19') + 1)
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
      WHERE table_id LIKE 'gsod194%'
```

> Second query:

```
#standardSQL
# Construct the second query based on the values from the first query
SELECT
  ROUND((max-32)*5/9,1) celsius
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod19*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '49'
```